# symbol not found for new functions added in vc++

Tags: visual-c++

In vc++ i added a new function and when i am clicking on goto definition it is showing an error that symbol not found .For old functions i am going to the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio's IntelliSense stuff takes a while to update sometimes either a) just try again in a few minutes or b) build your application. Even if the build fails this should update the database used by IntelliSense.

If all else fails, the d/b might be corrupted. Close Visual Studio, then find and delete the `<solution>.ncb` file and delete it. VS will rebuild it and all should be well. Usually!

Comment: @sun -- is it a new class or file? Does Goto Definition work for other functions in the same class or file?

Comment: yes for other func.s its working . i added new func in same class

Comment: @sun -- I have seen VS get in a state where there is one class where it can only find declarations but not definitions... but never where it can see some definitions but not others in a class. Sorry I'm out of ideas!

Comment: Isn't deleting the NCB file dangerous?

Comment: @DanGifford - no, not at all. VS can rebuild it. It isn't part of the source code (which is what you need to look after!), it's part of what VS creates.

Answer (score 1):

For VisualStudio 2010 at least, try closing VS and deleting the *projectname*.sdf and *projectname*.suo files.

Comment: Isn't this dangerous?